# gpg2: change someone's public key expiration date

Tags: gnupg

Is there a way to change someone's public key expiration date?

I have two keys for the same user - old (key A), with no expiration date, and current (key B), with expiration date in the future. I want to preserve the key A in the the key database, to be able to verify authenticity of old messages, but I don't want it used for any new communication (email).

I thought that I can use "gpg2 --edit-key" and the "expire", but I'm just getting "Need the secret key to do this.". I don't mind if the old key fingerprint will need to change.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change someone's public key expiration date?
> ...
> I thought that I can use "gpg2 --edit-key" and the "expire", but I'm just getting "Need the secret key to do this.".

The expiration date is contained in the key's self-signature data and therefore can only be changed with the private key. So, no, you cannot change someone else's public key expiration date.

> I have two keys for the same user - old (key A), with no expiration date, and current (key B), with expiration date in the future. I want to preserve the key A in the the key database, to be able to verify authenticity of old messages, but I don't want it used for any new communication (email).

You can disable the key, which will prevent it from being used for encrypting new messages. Do this in edit mode (`gpg2 --edit-key KEYID`) then typing `disable` at the prompt.